# Generate the random whole number in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How to Generate the random whole number in Dataweave 2.0, mule4, I am trying to use `{ price: randomInt(1000) as Number {format: "##"}}` but it's returning with Decimal

i.e result returned is 889.9 but I want "889.9" with double quotes.

Comment: What is it returning for you? I don't see any decimal coming out from that. Which version of Mule 4? Did you apply any DataWeave patches?

Comment: If you want a formatted number, you need to convert it into a String. In this case, with `as Number` the `format` is only used if you are casting from String to Number.  If you want a formatted number you need something like `as String {format: "##"}`

Comment: updated my question with example of the result expected

Comment: where do you see that result? in a client application? Please share the exact  and complete result (a JSON message?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you shared returns a Number object type and Numbers do not have "format", it's just represented differently depending on the serialization you choose (JSON, XML, Java, Binary, etc) or the client app you use to see the data.

If you want a number with a strict format, you need to convert it into a String like this:

```
{ price: randomInt(1000) as String {format: "#"}}
```

`"21" as Number {format: "##"}` is a valid expression but it's used to parse a String into a Number type.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add ceil or floor function to avoid these kind of issues.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    price: floor(randomInt(1000)) 
    // ceil(randomInt(1000))
}
```